# Xamarin studio update causing android application to crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.mac

With a recent update of xamarin (installed xamarin android N sdk, xamarin studio 6.1 etc) my android app is crashing when the device is disconnected from the debugger.
It works well when the debugger is connected to a device.

I have tried with Nexus 7, Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and Redmi Note 3. But it doesn't work when i try to run the app after disconnecting the device from the debugger.

Sharing the stack trace and the device log for the same. Please find the attached files.

Details of the xamarin studio and related stuff as below:
Xamarin Studio
Version 6.1 (build 5441)

Xamarin.Android
Version: 7.0.0.18
Android SDK: /Users/mkhairnar/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        6.0 (API level 23)
        7.0 (API level 24)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.2
SDK Platform Tools Version: 24.0.3
SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.2

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.11.5

Need your help to resolve the issue.

Stack Trace:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B01gNO4tBZyLa3FxRjJBSVlWVjJ1emJFdlBpZDkwU3RpU3cw/view?usp=sharing

Device Log:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B01gNO4tBZyLN2tVejRwRDdvYTFIeXFELVF2amJFUUJVQjFN/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Has the same issue. It was fixed by disabling shared mono runtime and fastdeploy even for debug mode.

Edit: Do not forget also to set linker to "SDK assemblies only"

[image]

[image]